# Wrong UV in render mode with Rain rig

Tags: rendering, materials, uv

The Rain rig that Blender provided here: https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da works fine for me with the viewport shading but when I render it got this result:

[image]

After checking the UV, it seems that there is 3 different textures called "TEX-rain_body_diffuse.1001.png", "TEX-rain_body_diffuse.1002.png" and "TEX-rain_body_diffuse.1003.png" with different resolutions for the skin material. The UV corresponding to the 1002 texture is moved
one unit to the right, and the 1003 is moved 2 units to the right, which seems pretty logic in fact:
[image]

But I think the first texture (TEX-rain_body_diffuse.1001.png) is repeating instead of taking the next images that corresponds to the UVs...

As I am the only one with this issue, I suppose there is a basic option I didn't check. Ah and obviously I automatically ran the script on the blend launch

I hope you can help me, and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You should to set pictures for Udim .

Read this [Link](https://artisticrender.com/how-udim-works-in-blender/)